# How to get full path from require.context?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, import

I want to include images to my website. I know that I can use `file-loader` and simply import image's path. But this method is not suitable for all cases. For example, sometimes I need to require dozens of photos, and these photo selection can variate from build to build.

As I understand in my case I should use `require.context`, because this way it can import all photos from specified directory. But here's a problem

```js
import ava from '@assets/photos/ava.jpg';
console.log(ava);
// /static/assets/photos/ava.jpg
console.log(require.context('@assets/photos', false, /ava.jpg$/).keys());
// ["./ava.jpg"]
```

`require.context` gives only the name of the file. Is there a way to get full path?

---

I know I could use these names and add to each of them `/static/assets/photos/` (and actually, this is how it works now), but this is seems to be a crutch.

Comment: Maybe use `"fs"`

Comment: Could you please give an example? As I understand `fs` works only for server-side, but I'm doing the front-end

Comment: You are right it only work on server side

Comment: If you're trying to use this file path from the client-side, what use is the full path anyway? The server's root isn't `/static` so you still end up having to trim off stuff at the start of the full path, and at that point you might as well generate the path directly with the name.

Comment: All I want is to get paths of images in whole directory, like with `import .. from`. I said nothing about server